# Drawing a straight line, and then curving along a circle

Tags: vectors, circles, curves

I am primarily a programmer, one with unfortunately relatively little education in mathematics, but I always try to get by. Right now, I am working with a simple set of rules. *Draw a straight line in a random direction at a random speed, and then generate a circle and begin drawing along the circle, and then leaving along the tangent.*

Attached is an image of what I am trying to do (excuse me for the rough sketch). From how I understand it, I have a vector, and I am drawing the circle with it's midpoint perpendicular to the line drawn. At this point, drawn in red, I need to begin moving along the circle for a period of time.

Does anyone have some tips on the math for drawing this? At this point I know that I need to continually update my vector, rotating, but I neither know what to do with the location at which the circle begins, maintaining the same speed as the straight line, etc.

And thanks for putting up with someone who never got much of a math education but really wants to understand more. My knowledge of math mainly comes through my interaction with programming, so these are always helpful exercises for me.

[image]

Comment: How are you drawing the line? Are you plotting points at some discrete time intervals? You said 'I need to continually update my vector', so I assume that this is the case.

Comment: Yes, and for the straight line, my vector works fine by generating a random number pair, multiplying it, and adding it to the current point.